# Open XBoX Web Browser from INgame

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

is it possible to open the web browser from inside a game menu and transfer account information like the emailadress of the Live accountvia the URL that is being pointed to?

Is it possible to open the browser reacting to a push notification?

Thanks,

Niko